# Capturing packets in an android application or ios application?

Tags: linux, android, ios, wireshark, packet

I've an android and ios app. They run on the same application server on Linux. I want to capture the packets when users are trying to log in to the app. How do I proceed? I'm thinking of doing it with tcpdump and putting that pcap file into wireshark. Will this work?

I am asking if this works because lots of change requests need to be done for this issue.

---

Below part is not relevant to the question but helps.

The issue that I am getting is called "Could not connect to server due to SSL Error" while trying to log in via android app.

Thus I'm trying to sniff the packets and figure out the root cause as I'm out of options to debug.

The problem is that the logs don't store anything till the user isn't logged in.

The nginx web server is just used for proxy pass. So, the packets need to be sniffed (between proxy and the server api which is hit after user is logged in successfully)

Comment: This sort of problem is where you need to have client-side logging. Most apps have a "enable troubleshooting mode" to trigger verbose logging to send to developers.

Answer (score -2):

You should use zAnti or cSploit on Android devices. They can do packet capture and more stuff like hacking and cracking. But you need to root the device to run them.

If you don't have root, you can use Packet Capture or tPacketCapture apps. They use a VPN service to capture packets. You can save the pcap file and open it in wireshark or other tools.

For ios devices, you need XCode and rvictl tools. You start the packet capture on your iphone and save it to your Mac to analyze it with wireshark or other tools.

Comment: The clients aren't tech savvy. So client side solution is not preferred.

Comment: Even if the users aren't tech-savvy, this problem requires a server-side solution or an end-device logging solution, not an end-device packet capture solution.

Comment: @schroeder I'm unable to make sense of your sentence. Can you clarify?

Comment: @barnyard9 this answer is not very useful because what's needed is something on the server or the client needs to log this specific data.